Player is jittering when colliding with a wall
When I move against the wall, the player starts jittering.
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Movement")]
    public float Speed = 4f;
    public float jumpPower = 3f;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private GroundCheck gr;

    private float horizontal;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        gr = GetComponent<GroundCheck>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        if (gr.grounded == true && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpPower);
        }
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * Speed, rb.velocity.y);
    }
}

this is how the problem looks like: https://imgur.com/a/A32jbxL
I don't know how to fix that.

jittering is always caused by continuing to move into the object thats blocking it

Cast a ray in the direction of movement to determine if the player will hit something, and reduce the velocity so that the player will only move the distance that he can.

You cannot update physics on Update like you are doing in line rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpPower);.
Move these logics to FixedUpdate and it should work.
Try this:
public class Movement2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Movement")]
    public float Speed = 4f;
    public float jumpPower = 3f;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private GroundCheck gr;

    private float horizontal;
    private bool jumping;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        gr = GetComponent<GroundCheck>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (gr.grounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            jumping = true;
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        var velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * Speed, rb.velocity.y);
        if (jumping)
        {
            jumping = false;
            velocity.y = jumpPower;
        }
        rb.velocity = velocity;
    }
}

Also try not to mix lowercase and uppercase characters:
public float Speed = 4f;
public float jumpPower = 3f;

